# How to use Optional in Netlogo Extensions

Tags: scala, netlogo

I want to create a netlogo primitive that may receive a boolean or may not. Therefore I want make possible to the user that he uses the primitive of these two ways:

1:

```
ask Walkers [
    qlearningextension:learning
]
```

2:

```
ask Walkers [
    qlearningextension:learning true
]
```

I tried to do that with OptionalType, but I could not make it. Is it possible to do what I want? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: what went wrong when you tried it? error messages? unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 2):

So `OptionalType` unfortunately only works with `CommandBlockType`.  For a good example of how that works, check out [the `sample-scala` extension](https://github.com/NetLogo/Sample-Scala-Extension/blob/hexy/src/SampleScalaExtension.scala#L36-L70) (maybe that's where you saw a reference to it in the first pace).  `OptionalType` will not work with `BooleanType`.

There is a secondary option, that's a little hacky.  You can use `RepeatableType` along with setting `defaultOption` and `minimumOption` in your syntax (so NetLogo knows that `0` arguments is okay/expected).  Scala code example:

```scala
object RepeatableTypeTest extends api.Command {
  override def getSyntax =
    commandSyntax(
      right = List(BooleanType | RepeatableType),
      defaultOption = Some(0),
      minimumOption = Some(0)
    )

  def perform(args: Array[api.Argument], context: api.Context) {
    println(args.length)
    if (args.length > 0) {
      val ref = args(0).getBoolean
      println(ref)
    } else {
      println("No argument given!")
    }
  }
}
```

Then you just have to wrap calls with the boolean argument in parenthesis, so NetLogo knows you're not starting a new command (it expects the `defaultOption` without the parens):

```
to test
  sample-scala:rep-bool
  (sample-scala:rep-bool true)
  (sample-scala:rep-bool false)
  (sample-scala:rep-bool false true false true false)
end
```

The problem with this, as you can see in the example, is if your users want to they can provide extra useless booleans: `(sample-scala:rep-bool false true false false true false false)`.  If your code ignores them they won't have an effect, but they could be confusing or weird to extension users.

Comment: No problem, if this (and other answers) got you what you needed, feel free to hit the accept button so others in the future will know what worked.